# Using interaction terms with quartile variables

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, econometrics, interaction

I was going over the old paper on insurance and healthcare utilization by the elderly by Hurd & McGarry (1997): http://www.econ.ucla.edu/mcgarry/papers_pdfs/JHE_hurd.pdf for a HealthEcon class.

Their baseline specification splits wealth and income into quartiles and then interacts them to predict Medicare uptake (Table 2). I have a very basic question, so given that they interact the quartiles, should they have also controlled for the individual effect of wealth and income in addition to the interaction term, or would they be overfitting the model?
Or is the purpose of the study satisfied by just looking at the joint effect of wealth and income quartiles?

Essentially it boils down to, how does these two specification contribute to the literature:

1. $ Y_{idt} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Incquart + \beta_2 Wealthquart + \beta_3 Incquart*Wealthquart + \delta X_idt  $

Vs.

$ Y_{idt} = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 Incquart*Wealthquart + \delta X_idt  $ This is whats essentially done in the paper.

I feel it may be important to get the effect of wealth and income alone before the interacted effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically one would want to control for main effects, as you've said. In this case, they've constructed the interaction in a rather unusual way by dummy coding the quartiles. As a result, the main effects are colinear with the interactions - adding them in won't change things. That being said, you would never want to interpret the interaction effect when it's specified this way, for the exact same reason.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. If I want to study impact of income and wealth quartiles and the interaction of the two, wouldn't the first specification I mentioned make more sense? This would omit collinear interaction and give main effects of wealth and income separately, while also showing the impact of belonging to different wealth and income quartiles jointly. Thanks.

Comment: Yes that's correct.